# Can someone explain to me what this JavaScript/Ajax part of code does?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm learning Ajax and I'm going through [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_suggest). What does this do? I don't understand the syntax `variable = function(){` how is a function being assigned to a variable?

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Functions are first class objects in java script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705173/what-is-meant-by-first-class-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know everyone is saying it's a callback specifically but the question you asked could better be answered by comparing what you're puzzled over with some more familiar code.

```
function myFunction()
{
    ...
}
```

So we know that calling `myFunction()` will run that code.

In Javascript, you can declare a function in a number of ways. This means that this:

```
var myFunction = function()
{
    ...
}
```

Does exactly the same as the first example above. It creates a function that you can call using `myFunction()`.

Add the callback into the mix in your question and we can see that

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    ...
}
```

is nothing more than assigning a function and containing code to the onreadystatechange property of object xmlhttp. Meaning that your code within the function will be called every time there is a state change in the xmlhttp object.

Answer (score 2):

When readyState changes, if request finished and response is ready (`readyState==4`) and document loaded correctly (HTTP Status Code `200` = OK!), append response text to the element with id `#txtHint`.

---

`onreadystatechange` stores a function (or the name of a function) to be called automatically each time the `readyState` property changes.

`readyState` holds the status of the XMLHttpRequest. Changes from 0 to 4:

- 0: request not initialized
- 1: server connection established
- 2: request received
- 3: processing request
- 4: request finished and response is ready

`status` takes HTTP response codes:

- 200: "OK"
- 404: Page not found

Answer (score 1):

`onreadystatechange` is a callback. It gets triggered when a particular event happens. `onreadystate` is happens when the requests ready state changes.

In short `onreadystate`

```
Stores a function (or the reference of a function) to be called automatically each time the readyState property changes
```

Now for the line
`xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200`

`readyState : Holds the status of the XMLHttpRequest.`

```
 Changes from 0 to 4: 
0: request not initialized 
1: server connection established
2: request received 
3: processing request 
4: request finished and response is ready
```

And `status` Holds status

```
200: "OK"
404: Page not found
```

So `xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200` condition is true when the response is ready and there is no issues

`xmlhttp.responseText` contains the response sent from the server.

So `document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;` changes the HTML of  the element with id `txtHint` to the response that was received.

Hope all the above made sense!!!

Comment: I've never been able to understand callbacks. `onreadystatechange` gets triggered when a particular event happens. What does this have to do with a call back?

Comment: A call to a function when a particular event occurs is called `callback`. Does it make sense now??

Comment: What do you mean when a particular event occurs? Just calling a function normally wouldn't be considered a callback right.

Comment: Thats one example. Read http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/ for a better understanding

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to address this comment: `I've never been able to understand callbacks.`

Consider this analogy:

> You need want to rent that movie that just came out on VHS, so you
>   call Blockbuster and ask the attendant if they have a copy.  Sadly
>   though, they are super busy dealing with thousands of David Bowie fans
>   who are trying to rent "Labyrinth" all at the same time and he does't
>   have time to look up the information for you. So instead, he asks for
>   your phone number.  At some point in the future when the hordes of
>   people have left and he has the time, he looks up the info you need,
>   and calls you back on the number you provided. Turns out the movie is
>   sold out though, so he suggests "Dark Crystal" instead.

In your case you are dealing with an entity that is going to take a long time to do it's work as it needs to talk to remote servers, so it essentially asks you for your phone number so that when it's done you are called back as it were, with the requested data.

Does it make more sense now?

Comment: A long time ago my friend who hates computers took a class with me. When he asked the teacher what a key (in an array) was she said "it's like a key to the post boxes in an apartment building". I'm not a huge fan of learning through analogies/metaphors. When you say "you are dealing with an entity that is going to take a long time to do it's work" what does it matter? It's got nothing better to do? There's no instructions it can do in the mean time.

Comment: @Celeritas Just because that's the cause in your specific example doesn't mean that's the general case.  Consider this - Javascript is single threaded. If you made an ajax call that took maybe 3 seconds, (totally reasonable) you would completely lock up any other script on the page and kill all user interaction during that period.  Still think there are no instructions to be run in the mean time?

Comment: @Celeritas Also the teachers analogy was not that great, besides arrays have indexes not keys.