# jQuery: Why use anonymous functions as argument?

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function

In trying to grasp some fundamentals of jQuery and JavaScript at the same time, I'm a little confused as to why jQuery takes an anonymous function as an argument. Like this:

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

as opposed to this:

```
$( "#target" ).click(alert("You clicked it."));
```

In jQuery's own ["101" guide](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/functions/), they point out that "Passing functions as arguments is an extremely common idiom in jQuery." But they don't seem to explain why. Is it just to provide a wrapper for a block of expressions, or (I suspect) much more than that?

Comment: Your second one is a syntax error (_SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list_) - did you mean `$("#target").click(alert, "You clicked it.");`?

Comment: `is it just to provide a wrapper for a block of expressions` - do you know any other effective means to do that without using functions?

Comment: That part of my question was if it were *just* for that. Or rather, is there something else to using an anonymous function there beyond wrapping expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first param to `click` is a callback function.  A callback function is executed after the click event.

[Functions](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html) in javascript [are first class objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705173/what-is-meant-by-first-class-object).  This means they can be passed as parameters.  You could pass `alert` to the `click` method.  But in your second example you are not passing it, you are calling it ([see Doorknob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19612923/594589))!

Answer (score 5):

To answer your specific question, the reason is because this code:

```
$( "#target" ).click(alert("You clicked it.");
```

does the following:

1. Calls `alert` with `"You clicked it."` as parameter
2. Binds **the result of that `alert` call** (which is `undefined`) as a click handler for `#target`.

In other words, `alert` is called immediately and `undefined` is bound as the event handler, which makes no sense.

Whereas with the first code snippet:

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

1. An anonymous function is created [ `alert( "Handler for .click() called." );` ]
2. And the result of that expression (a function) is bound as an event handler

For more information of anonymous functions, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140089/how-does-an-anonymous-function-in-javascript-work?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, it would actually call click with `undefined`. Try it:

```
> alert
function alert() { [native code] }
> alert('test')
undefined
```

This is because the `alert` function returns `undefined`, so you're actually calling the method with `undefined` as the argument.

> Is it just to provide a wrapper for a block of expressions

Well, how else would you do it? The **only** way to express "a block of expressions" in JavaScript is... you guessed it: functions.

Comment: Right. I get that's what functions are for. I wanted to know if it was merely for that reason, or something more.

Answer (score 1):

Well, passing functions as arguments is an extremely common idiom in *JavaScript*. Sometimes you need to pass a callback function to another function, for example an event handler, and you don't need to define it separately and give it a name. If you need to call that function somewhere else too, then you define it separately with its own name, but if you need it only in one place, then there is no need to give it a name.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information re: anonymous vs named.