# did a little javascript experiment, needs your help to understand the unexpected results

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, javascript-objects

I did an JavaScript experiment in browser's console -

First I created a new object foo as following

```
  var foo = {
    bar: function() { return this.baz; },
    baz: 1
  };
```

Now when I run the following code again in console it returns `"number"`

```
  (function(){
    return typeof foo.bar();
  })();
```

But when I run following anonymous function it returns `"undefined"`

```
  (function(){
    return typeof arguments[0]();
  })(foo.bar);
```

As far as I know `arguments[0]` in above function return `foo.bar` (also proved by the following example) then why the above code returns `"undefined"` instead of `"number"`?

---

When I run

```
      (function(){
        return arguments[0];
      })(foo.bar);
```

returns `function () { return this.baz; }`

---

Also

```
  (function(){
    return typeof arguments[0];
  })(foo.bar());
```

Returns `"number"` then why not

```
  (function(){
    return typeof arguments[0]();
  })(foo.bar);
```

returns the same? Is there any fundamental law in JavaScript that is working here?

Comment: In second test, you pass foo.bar as the argument but foo.bar is not a property, it's a function. You could try passing foo.bar() as the argument and inspect the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me simplify the problem ...

```
var foo = {
    bar: function() { return this.baz; },
    baz: 1
};


var ref = foo.bar;

console.log(typeof ref()); // undefined
console.log(typeof foo.bar()); // number
```

It is because 'this' inside the function object 'bar' does not always refer to 'foo'. It changes on how you call it. If you call it from an object not foo it will show undefined. Note that ref is not foo but foo.bar.

Now if you change foo to the following it will give 'number' output in both cases ...

```
var foo = {
    bar: function() { return foo.baz; },
    baz: 1
};
```

Note that

```
console.log(ref === foo.bar); // true
```

but foo.bar() is not equal to ref() (In first case) because when you call foo.bar() the javascript engine passes foo as 'this' but when you call ref() which is originally window.ref(), it passes window object (or other global object in case of non-browser environment) as 'this'

Answer (score 2):

`this` depends on **how** you call the function. When using dot notation, JavaScript sets the context of `this` to the receiver. In your case there is no receiver, but a reference to the function, so you lost the context. You have to pass it explicitly:

```
arguments[0].call(foo);
```

`arguments[0]` is the same function object as `foo.bar` but the value of `this` is dynamic. In `foo.bar()`, `this` gets assigned to `foo` because you used `foo.` (dot notation). But in `arguments[0]()` there's no dot (no receiver) so `this` is the default value, or `window`.

It's the same function but different invocation.

Comment: I think `arguments[0]` is same as `foo.bar`. `foo.bar()` works here correctly (second test) and `arguments[0]()` not, why?

Comment: It is the same function object, but `this` is dynamic. In `foo.bar` `this` gets assigned to `foo` because you used `foo.` (dot notation). But in `arguments[0]()` there's no dot (no receiver) so `this` is the default value, or `window`.

Comment: Would you please explain how exactly JavaScript interpreter works. Like it first replace `arguments[0]` with `foo.bar`, then `arguments[0]()` becomes same as `foo.bar()`, then it try to run `foo.bar()`. How different is this process from second test. Is `arguments[0]` works differently?

Comment: There is a `.` that's what makes the difference. `foo.bar` vs `arguments[0]`. Notice that there's a dot in the former but not the later. It's the same function but different invocation.

Comment: It's not the `.` that makes `arguments[0]()` and `foo.bar()` different. It's how JavaScript interprets `arguments[0]()` and `foo.bar()`. In the case of `arguments[0]()` JavaScript first valuate `arguments[0]` as `function () { return this.baz; }` which become `function () { return this.baz; }()` and returns `undefined` because `this` refer to window object, and in the case of `foo.bar()` `function () { return this.baz; }()` is returned as a method of `foo`. You explained "What happened" well but not the "how?". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Elaboration on elclanrs' answer.

`foo.bar` is a method; an instruction of how to do something.  In object-oriented programming languages, the only object that can use that instruction is a `foo` or an object related to `foo`; but in JavaScript, anybody can try to run it if the code asks them to.

In your second anonymous function, you are getting a method to run, running it, and returning the type of the result.  However, it's not a `foo` that is running this function; it's anonymous, so the `window` is the object that's running it.  The `window` runs `foo`, which tries to return `this.baz`; however, the `window` doesn't HAVE a `baz`, so that's why you're getting undefined.

To test it further, try setting `window.baz` and see if you get the right result, and also try elclanrs' suggestion of using the `call()` method to ensure it gets called from a `foo`'s scope.

**EDIT**

You're right, the type of `arguments[0]` and `foo.bar` IS the same; they're both "function".  I think the confusion is over JavaScript's treatment of functions as first-class objects.

If you're familiar with object-oriented languages like Java or C++, then you would expect that when you call `bar`, it's always being called by a `foo` that has a `baz` property; however, this isn't the case in JavaScript.  Any function can be called by ANY object, which means the result may or not make sense.

The difference between the two, as elclanrs says, is all about the `.`.  Let's say I made my own object `phew = {baz: 44}`.  I could, validly, "steal" a method from `foo` like this: `phew.myMethod = foo.bar`.  Now, `phew` knows the instructions contained in `bar`, and if I call `phew.myMethod()`, I would get 44 as my result because `phew` is calling the method, and `phew`'s `baz` is 44; it doesn't matter *where* the method is defined!  All that matters is *what the method says to do*, and `bar` says to return the `baz` of whoever called it.

So now, going back to your code, you're calling `arguments[0]()`.  It does seem like it should be the same, but because functions are first-class objects, when you passed it as a parameter, all you really passed was a function called `bar`.  When you called `arguments[0]()`, it was like calling `bar()`, which is different from calling `foo.bar()` just like it's different from calling `phew.myMethod()`, **even though they all are exactly the same function**.

For more info, try [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705173/what-is-meant-by-first-class-object)

Comment: Actually you didn't answered my question. What I don't understand is how `arguments[0]` id different from `foo.bar` ? Both returns the same function `function () { return this.baz; }` then why `arguments[0]()` use global object but the `foo.bar()` not?

Comment: `arguments[0]()` is different from `foo.bar()` because it first valuate `arguments[0]` as `function () { return this.baz; }` which is not a method of object `foo`. While `foo.bar()` runs as a method of `foo`.

Comment: Actually if you put 

  console.log(foo.bar === arguments[0])

inside the anonymous function it shows true. where as if you write two same function they will not be equal.