# calling a function using a mouse event without attaching it to an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html

I am taking a web development class. Today the teacher gave us a piece of code that raised some questions that I haven't been able to satisfactorily solve through my own searching. The code in question was essentially this:

```
<script>
function selectmouse(e){
...
...
}

document.onmousedown = selectmouse;
</script>
```

My first question, is this a legitimate way of calling functions? Is this something that is done? I am of course familiar with the typical way of calling functions from HTML elements, for example

```
<body onmousedown="selectmouse(event)">
```

The code was supposed to be calling the function and passing it the event object for the onmousedown. After playing with the code for a while I found a few unusual things.

First, if I put parenthesis after the function call, like I am used to doing (i.e. selectmouse();), then the function resolved immediately upon loading the page, with a value of 'undefined' for the variable. This makes intuitive sense to me, because I assume the browser is treating it like a variable assignment and therefore calling the function as it parses the code, as it normally would to assign a variable.

However the part that is weird to me happened when I deleted the '()' and left it as it is coded above. In this instance it seemed to function like she wanted it to. It would call the function when the mouse was pressed in any part of the body, and it sent the event object as the variable for the function. But I can't figure out why. I can't find reference to anything similar to it online, and I've never seen anything like it before. Is this a legitimate way to do something like this? Or is this bad code that happens to be working for some reason and would probably cause problems in the future? Why is it working?

Comment: For call to a function you must have select document or its html ....

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is meant by 'first class object'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705173/what-is-meant-by-first-class-object)

Comment: Ideally, it should be `document.addEventListener('mousedown', selectmouse, false)`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: I'd like to call into question your accusation that your teacher is *incompetent*. It seems she at least knows more than her students which I'd say is a good start.

Comment: Agreed @Phil. It's like writing "My totally incompetent coworker used in-line styles AND tables for an HTML e-mail!! YUCK...LOL.Everyone knows those are bad... Anyway, why doesn't this work..."

Comment: While I probably shouldn't have led this question with that statement, I assure you the accusation was based off of much more than just this code piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.onmousedown = selectmouse;  //note: never do this except in old browsers
```

> However the part that is weird to me happened when I deleted the '()' and left it as it is coded above. In this instance it seemed to function like she wanted it to.

That's not weird. You are passing the reference of the function to the browser, not executing it.

For example, you have this function:

```
function callback(){
    alert("clicked!");
}

document.body.onclick = callback;
```

You pass the reference to `onclick` and the browser will know what function to call when the event is triggered. But if you do it like this:

```
document.body.onclick = callback();
```

This will be evaluated into:

```
document.body.onclick = alert("clicked!");
//Note that this is simplified explanation to visualize what is happening.
//The returned value of alert() is not assigned to onclick.
//To be exact the returned value of callback() is the one that is being assigned.
//Similar to:
//  ...onclick = (function(){ alert("clicked!"); })();
```

Then you will see an alert, and the browser will continue executing the rest of the code:

```
document.body.onclick = undefined;
```

---

```
<body onmousedown="selectmouse(event)">     <!-- Don't do this too -->
```

The parentheses are necessary because this code is not executed instantly. It is only executed when the event is triggered.

---

Anyway, you shouldn't attach events both using `.onmousedown` or `onmousdown="..."`. There is a better way of doing it:

```
element.addEventListener("mousedown", callback, false);
```

Reason: If you use the `onmousedown` property, you can only attach one `mousedown` event. In most cases you would want to attach *more* than one.

Also attaching events inline *might* cause security problems ([cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)), and that is exactly [why Google decided to prohibit all developers from using them](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution) in developing Chrome apps/extensions.

Comment: I wouldn't say *never*. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Older_way_to_register_event_listeners (scroll down to *Older way to register event listeners*, MDN's title links are broker on that page)

Comment: Too true! I just think *never* is a bit strong :)

Comment: Ok I've worked my way through everything you said here along with the google link and the mozilla link. Thanks for the help. I'm pretty sure I've got a pretty good handle on it, although of course I'll need to practice with it. I'm surprised to hear that inline calls are not supposed to be used anymore, considering how ubiquitous they have been in everything I've seen or worked with so far.

Comment: @SometimesDirty - If you take a look at the source of your favorites sites, you would find that most of the time inline events are not used anymore. They are outdated and not so good for future maintenance. And who still manually attach events when you have jQuery and AngularJS? ;)

Comment: Your sample regarding the onlick/alert is not correct.  onclick will remain undefined as the callback function does not return anything

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, the bit that is wrong is `document.body.onclick = alert("clicked!");`.  The browser will not unwrap the function body and assign it to the handler

Comment: @RobertSlaney - I was just trying to describe it in a way that can be easily understood. Perhaps I should add comments to clarify this bit.

Answer (score 0):

This is legitimate code and is working as it should.

The way you are comfortable with is just a method we tried while the web was evolving, but at present we should better use the second way you showed, although its changed bit more to make you understand it in a better way using event bindings.

When you do

```
function selectmouse(e){
...
...
}
```

javascript will create a variable named `selectmouse` and save the function in that variable. So `selectmouse` is a variable of type `function` with the function body as its value.

`document` on the other hand can be related to `class` or specifically an `object` which is an instance. Each `document` and each HTML element or `DOM node` can have in it variables to store the functions to be called on user events like `onmousedown`.

so when doing

```
document.onmousedown = selectmouse;
```

we are inturn saying

> when mousedown happens in document, the function named selectmouse
>   should be called

If you do

```
document.onmousedown = selectmouse();
```

it means

> run the function selectmouse immediately and get the result, assign
>   the result to onmousedown event of the DOM Node document.

And if you ask why this is taken apart from the form

```
<body onmousedown="selectmouse(event)">
```

To answer in a simple way, HTML is Hyper Text Markup Language, its sole purpose is to represent formatted data, the quick evolution of web inturn made it deranged with `behaviours` like this and `presentation` code like inline css. So to make behaviour and presentation out of HTML and thus a better design we do this.

Please take time to take a look at how you can `bind` a function to an event which is the current tradeoff in doing this same thing.

**For a detailed explanation please check the events sectio of ppk blog [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/contents.html)**

Comment: I'm confused by this. The second way I showed IS the way I'm comfortable with, where as the first way is the one I have a question about.

Comment: Your answer makes a lot more sense now, thanks a lot. I am going to spend some time working my through the link you provided.

Answer (score -1):

I think that is correct, because the function is being called within the script as if it were an object, to me is not the best way to do it, I would have like this (with jquery):

```
$(document).mousedown(function (event) {
  // here the content of the function
 });
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<body onmousedown="selectmouse(event)">
```

In this example the browser *evaluates* the result of the expression **selectmouse(event)** and assigns it to the onmousedown property of the body, event is undefined and the selectmouse doesn't return anything so it's result is undefined.

It is equivalent of the following if it was inside a script tag

```
<script>
    function selectmouse(e) {
    }

    document.body.onmousedown = selectmouse(event);
</script>
```

---

```
<body onmousedown="selectmouse">
```

When you remove the () you are assigning a function to the onmousedown property.  Now the browser fires your callback method whenever the mousedown event is raised *and it bubbles up to the body*, passing the current event as the parameter you're declaring as "e".  If another element also had an onmousedown event handler declared but it cancelled the event ( by calling event.cancelBubble = true ) the body's onmousedown handler will *not* be invoked.

```
<script>
    function selectmouse(e) {
    }

    document.body.onmousedown = selectmouse;
</script>
```