# Are functions really first class objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS. I heard that functions can be manipulated like values in this language. So I tried writing a code that asks the user for a function, then call this function, which should be alright. But it doesn't work, the code is :

```
   <SCRIPT language=javascript>
    var input;
   (function PromptMessage() {
       input = prompt("type the function you want called")
    })()
    input();
</SCRIPT>
```

And in the prompt box I type `function () {alert("I am an alert box!");}`

But it doesn't work, I don't see the alert. Am I doing something wrong or it is that the only callable functions are defined in the source code ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is meant by 'first class object'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705173/what-is-meant-by-first-class-object)

Comment: @SeanVieira The OP is asking *'is x a first class object'*, not *'what is a first class object'*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the question is about invoking a function string, so here it goes:

```js
 var input;
  (function PromptMessage() {
       input = prompt("type the function you want called")
  })();

 function getFunctionBody(s) {
    var match = s.toString().match(/function[^{]+\{([\s\S]*)\}$/);
    return match ? match[1] : s;
 }
  
Function(getFunctionBody(input))();
```

enter the string in the prompt

`function () {alert("I am an alert box!");}`

and you should get the alert.

It's a little more work to take account of function parameters, but I'll leave that up to you as an exercise.

The `Function` constructor is safer than `eval` because it runs in it's own scope and doesn't have access to outside scope.

Comment: Thanks for this alternative solution, eval() works, but I didn't think of returning a string in a function whose return type is function so that it will be casted to a function and thus callable (that's what your code does right ?)

Comment: Yep, and it's safer than eval because it doesn't have access to outside it's scope.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, functions are first class objects.

```js
function one() {
  alert("Hello");  
}

function runAnotherFunction(anotherFunction) {
  anotherFunction();  
}

runAnotherFunction(one);
```

The return value of the `prompt` function, however, is a *string*.

A string containing JavaScript code is still a string and can't be called as if it was a function.

You could `eval` it, but that is usually a terrible idea (as is asking users to write raw JS to inject into your program in the first place).

Comment: Thanks so it was a type problem. I know that asking the user for a function is a bad idea, but it was just for fun, as it is the first thing I thought about that would not be possible to do in Java or C++. So now it works with eval !

Comment: The Function constructor function is more-or-less eval by another name.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function PromptMessage() {
       var input = prompt("type the function you want called");
       eval(input)();
})()
```

Would do what you want, you need to evaluate the string to make it a function. Don't do this in a real website.

Answer (score 0):

prompt is return string and string is not a function;
use eval is execute you data like js
     `var input;
      (function PromptMessage() {
          input = prompt("type the function you want called")
      })()
      eval(input);`