# Function with multiple nested functions returned

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript and I have a trouble to understand the following javascript code. So is it possible for you guys to shed me the light on what is the purpose of having multiple functions nested inside the return. What is it for, why we need it and when we should use it.

Many thanks in advance

```
function create() {
   var counter = 0;
   return {
      increment: function() {
         counter++;
      },

      print: function() {
         console.log(counter);
      }
   }
}
var c = create();
c.increment();
c.print();
```

Comment: Err. The functions do different things, so there are more than one of them. And its an *object* holding multiple functions that is returned.

Comment: this separates public and private api - eg. counter is private, and the returned api is public

Comment: Reading some books/tutorials about not-easy parts of JavaScript will help to understand.

Comment: @Regent: Can you suggest some good books

Comment: "JavaScript the good parts" is an excellent book.

Comment: @guruvn nope, I can not (I actually didn't read any books about JS), but Google can suggest many books, and some of them are supposed to be good ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand this you need to understand two key concepts:

1. In JavaScript functions are [first class objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705173/what-is-meant-by-first-class-object)
2. [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

The `create` function returns an object that has two fields who's values are actually functions and that both have a closure that contains the `counter` variable. So the `c` variable is assigned an object (which is created by the `create` function) and that object has two functions that you can simply call that both reference the same counter variable.