# Load and parse multiple csv files with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm implementing a map visualization using D3.js. I have a number of x csv files (matrices). I want to load them and sum all values from all files.

I implemented a for loop over the array of names and load and parse the data using `d3.text`, but due to async behavior, I can't find a way to do this (I get `undefined` from `console.log` first and then the result of the for loop).

I've tried to use async.js but I cant figure out how to allow the flow of the for loop. Here is my code:

```
var total=[];
var matrix=[];

for(var i=0; i<filenames.length; i++){

    d3.text(filenames[i], function(text){
      matrix = d3.csv.parseRows(text).map(function (row){
        return row.map(function(value){ 
          return +value;
        });
      });
    });

    //sum the matrix pseudocode
    for(...){
      total = total + matrix;
    }
}

//here I need the sum of all files and then do other stuffs with the total:
console.log(total);
...
...
```

How can I archieve this? Thanks.

Comment: what exactly do you mean with sum of all files?
do you want to concatenate them? or do you want to sum the values of all files to a single number?

Comment: sum the values of the matrices in the files to get the total. @jhinzmann

Comment: just realized this is your first question on stackoverflow, so welcome to the community :) i hope my answer calculates the sum the way you wanted it to be. If there is still something unclear to you just ask ;) If not, feel free to accept the answer. That way others can see, that your problem is solved and what answer did the job if they have the same problem.

Comment: @jhinzmann's answer looks like a good simple solution, which might be just what you need. Just as an alternative, if you'd like to use a library, consider mbostock's [queue](https://github.com/mbostock/queue).

Comment: @meetamit I should have known that [micheal](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/) has coded something for this case :D thanks for the hint ;)

Comment: @jhinzmann thanks! this works as i wanted to (with some adjustments), but I still have a problem. I need to process the result of the sum after the call of the function. I tried this but doesn´t work: var sum2= loadFilesAndCalculateSum(filenames, function(sum){ console.log(sum); return sum; }); what can I do in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you do it with a recursive function.

In the following example you can use `loadFilesAndCalculateSum()` like the `d3.text()` but instead of one string it takes an array of strings and the callback gets the calculated sum instead of the text of a file.

```
/**
 * load all files and calculate the sum of the values
 * @param  {Array}    filenames Array with filenames as string
 * @param  {Function} cb        Callback function, gets the sum as param
 * @param  {number}   sum       The initial sum   
 * @param  {number}   i         Starting index for filenames
 * @return {void}
 */
function loadFilesAndCalculateSum(filenames, cb, sum, i) {
  sum = sum || 0;
  i = i || 0;
  d3.text(filenames[i], function(error, text) {
    //parse the rows and reduce them
    sum += d3.csv.parseRows(text).reduce(function(prev, curr) {
      //return previous sum + this rows sum
      return prev + d3.sum(curr, function(d){return +d;})
    },0); 

    if(i < filenames.length - 1){
      //load next file
      loadFilesAndCalculateSum(filenames, cb, sum, i+1);
    } else {
      //call the callback with the final sum
      cb(sum);
    }
  });
}

var filenames = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"];

loadFilesAndCalculateSum(filenames, function(sum){
  //do something with the total sum
  console.log(sum);
});
```

To clarify this. you have to do the processing of sum inside of the callback function where I put the comment `do something with the total sum`. This function is still executing async. That means, that everything you write after the `loadFilesAndCalculateSum()` function will possibly execute before the code inside the callback. You can find a little longer introduction to **[async javascript here](http://rowanmanning.com/posts/javascript-for-beginners-async/)**

```
//this is executed first
//....
loadFilesAndCalculateSum(filenames, function(sum){
  //do something with the total sum
  //this is executed third, when all files are loaded and the sum is calculated
  console.log(sum);
});

//code after this point is executed second, while the files are being loaded.
```

If you already have a function that does something with the sum, you can pass this function to the `loadFilesAndCalculateSum` as second parameter. This is possible because functions are so called **[first class citizens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/705184/3874924)**:

```
var addthis = 5;

function doSomethingWithTheSum(sum) {
  //everything you want to do with the sum goes inside this function.

  //from here you could call other functions and pass the sum.
  soSomethingDifferentWithTheSum(sum);

  //or you use the sum inside this function
  console.log(sum);
  var newsum = sum + addthis;
  console.log(sum);

  d3.select("whatever")
      .data([sum])
      .enter()
    .append("text")
      .text(function(d){ return d;});
}

loadFilesAndCalculateSum(filenames, doSomethingWithTheSum);
```

You can pass functions just like any other variable. in the first example I called the second parameter of the `loadFiles...` function `cb` which is the usual abbreviation for `callback`. As stated in the doc comment, this param should be of type `Function`.

In the end of the `loadFiles...` function I the callback function gets called by

```
....
//call the callback with the final sum
cb(sum);
....
```

Here the sum is given to the callback function as first parameter. Therefore if you pass a function, it should take a single param, like the anonymous function in the first example or the `doSomethingWithTheSum` function in the example above.

Comment: thanks! this works as i wanted to (with some adjustments), but I still have a problem. I need to process the result of the sum after the call of the function. I tried this but doesn´t work: var sum2= loadFilesAndCalculateSum(filenames, function(sum){ console.log(sum); return sum; }); what can I do in that case?

Comment: just edited my answer. I hope this helps you to understand what is going on there. Please have a look at the `loadFilesAnd...` function. There is no `return` statement. This function does not return anything. Therefore you can't use it like `var sum2 = loadFilesAnd...`