# D3.js: Load flat 1-dimensional array via d3.csv results in "TypeError: groupData is undefined" / Load multiple CSV files with D3.js

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, d3.js

I use the function **exampleData()** to generate a flat, 1-dimensional array that is used to generate SVG elements with d3.js (vesion 3.5.5). That works perfectly.

But when I use the below mentioned function **load()** [like dataset = load();], this leads to the error **TypeError: groupData is undefined d3.v3.js:1688:31** .

Can anyone help? The file data.csv has a column header called *x* and 20 additional rows with one integer in each row . The arrays seems to be okay when querying at he console of the webbrowser.

Best , Frank

```js
function exampleData() {
  return  [ 11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25,5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13];
}
```

---

```js
function load() {
 d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
    dataset2 = data.map(function(d) { 
     return [ +d["x"] ];
     });
    //console.log(dataset2);
    dataset2= d3.merge(dataset2);
    //console.log(data);
    return dataset2;
  });

}
```

Comment: There is no `groupData` in your example and you have not indicated which line throws the error. Without that it is impossible to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the code you provided doesn't throw any errors like the one you describe, i guess the error occures when you try to work with the loaded dataset, because with `dataset = load()`, `dataset` will be `undefined`.

The problem with your code is, that `load()` does not have a return statement.

Actually `load()` can't even return anything because `d3.csv()` loads data **asynchronous**. `d3.csv()` does not return anything. It starts a request for the given `csv` and when this request finishes, it calls the callback function.

When you call `load()` in your code, the next line after the call will probably be executed before the data is loaded. If you try it this way:

```
function load() {
  d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
    dataset2 = data.map(function(d) { 
      return [ +d["x"] ];
    });
    dataset2= d3.merge(dataset2);
    console.log(dataset2);
  });
}

load();
console.log("afterLoad");
```

The `afterLoad` will be logged first. Later on, when the data is loaded, the dataset will be logged.

Therefore you have to handle your data inside the `callback`. Probably you should have another function that draws your chart. You have to call this function from the callback function like this:

```
function load() {
  d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
    dataset2 = data.map(function(d) { 
      return [ +d["x"] ];
    });
    //console.log(dataset2);
    dataset2= d3.merge(dataset2);
    //console.log(data);
    //call the function that needs the data
    drawMyChart(dataset2);
  });
}
```

Since you named your dataset `dataset2` i guess there is more than one dataset. I gave an explanation on loading multiple csv files in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30768019/3874924). Maybe this will help you understanding the concept of asynchronous programming.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I heard about the asynchronous behaviour of `d3.csv()`. Your example is a good use case to **understand** this "special" behaviour.

Comment: What I wanted to achieve is to load different CSV files whenever there is a mouse click on a button with the ID = "click1", "click2", etc. And I wanted to solve it this way:
   `d3.select("#click1")
    .on("click", function() {
 //New values for dataset
 dataset = load();
 // .....
 });`

But your answer with the function `load()` with the chart drawing within the function is exactly what I need. If I use the function with an input value like `load(filename) {d3.csv(filename, ....}`, then I should have the solution I need.