# Limit row numbers in JavaScript input generating script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello how I can limit the number of the generated inputs to 10 in this JavaScript example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rowNum = 0;
function addRow(frm) {    
    rowNum ++;
    var row = '<div id="itemRows"><label for="file_01">File 01</label><input type="file"  name="file[]" multiple>';
    jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);

}

function removeRow(rnum) {
    jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a check for the `rowNum` when both adding and removing, and prohibit adding whenever you are at 10 and removing whenever you are at 0

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rowNum = 0;
function addRow(frm) {
    if (rowNum < 10) {   
        rowNum ++;
        var row = '<div id="itemRows"><label for="file_01">File 01</label><input type="file"  name="file[]" multiple>';
        jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
    }

}

function removeRow(rnum) {
    if (rowNum > 0) {
        jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
        rowNum--;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put in a for loop. There is no iteration in your script.

```
    function addRow(frm) {    
        rowNum ++;
        for(i; i<10; i++){
            var row = '<div id="itemRows"><label for="file_01">File 01</label><input type="file"  name="file[]" multiple>';
            jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the counter to the function (functions are [first class objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705173/what-is-meant-by-first-class-object) and properties like this make sense). [Pollution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862665/what-does-it-mean-global-namespace-would-be-polluted) of the global namespace is not recommended.

```
function addRow() {
    if (!addRow.counter) {
        addRow.counter = 0;
    }

    addRow.counter++;

    if (addRow.counter > 10) {
        // whatever needed
    }
}
```