# Functions in js copied/passed by value or reference

Tags: javascript

I know that objects in Javascript are copied/passed by reference. But what about functions?

I was trying out this code when I jumped to something confusing. Here is the code snippet:

```js
x = function() { console.log('hey 1'); }

y = x;

x = function() { console.log('hey 2'); }

y; // Prints function() { console.log('hey 1'); }
```

If functions like objects are copied/passed by reference, why y is not updated to print 'hey 2'?

If this behavior is because 'x' is assigned with a brand new function, is there any way for variable 'y' to the newly assigned function when x changes?

Comment: This behavior is identical to the behavior you'd see if you did `{ x: 1 }` and `{ x: 2 }` instead of `function() { console.log('hey 1'); }` and `function() { console.log('hey 2'); }`. your current phrasing makes it sound like you're observing different patterns for objects versus functions, which cannot be the case.

Comment: A constant I've seemed to find in almost all programming languages is that the `=` operator will only modify the variable it refers to (as in, the actual reference "x") and not the underlying data. If a type has a `.modify()` or `.add()` method, that is one way that underlying data can change so as to be visible via multiple variables.

Comment: Sorry - self-caveat: In JavaScript, `=` is used to modify the properties of an object, which can certainly be visible by other references. eg: `var b = a; a.myprop = 3; console.log(b.myprop);`

Comment: *"If functions like objects are copied/passed by reference, why y is not updated to print 'hey 2'?"* You are making false assumptions. Everything is **pass-by-value** in JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything in JS is **pass by value** where the value for objects and functions is a reference.

What is happening here is the same thing that would happen with an object (since functions are just [first-class objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/705184/3928341)):

Here's the gist of what's going on:

```
x = function() { console.log('hey 1'); }
```

> `x` points to `function() that logs 1` (memory is created for this function)

```
y = x;
```

> `y` points to `function() that logs 1` (same memory location)

```
x = function() { console.log('hey 2'); }
```

> `x` now points to a **new** `function() that logs 2` ( a new memory space), nothing affected `y` though

```
y;
```

> `y` still points to the same `function() that logs 1`

---

If you want to have changes to `x` affect `y`, what you should do is change the thing **they are pointing to**, not change **what they point to**.

For example:

```
var pointingAtMe = { log: function() { console.log('1'); } }
var x = pointingAtMe;
var y = pointingAtMe;

// change the actual thing x and y are both pointing to
x.log = function() { console.log('2'); } // this line also sets `y.log` and `pointingAtMe.log`since they all point to the same thing
// and the change gets applied to both
y.log(); // logs '2'
```

Answer (score 1):

> If functions like objects are copied/passed by reference, why y is not updated to print 'hey 2'?

You are making false assumptions. Everything is [**pass-by-value**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) in JavaScript. It's correct that objects are *represented as* references, but that is different from [*pass-by-reference*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference).

Even if you used a plain object instead of a function, you wouldn't see what you expected:

```
var x = {foo: 42};
var y = x;
x = {foo: 21};
console.log(y.foo); // still 42
```

---

*Pass-by-value/reference* only describes how *variables* and *parameters* are resolved, it doesn't have anything to do with the value of the variables.

> If this behavior is because 'x' is assigned with a brand new function, is there any way for variable 'y' to the newly assigned function when x changes?

No. Not without explicitly assigning to `y`.

Answer (score 0):

`x = function() { console.log('hey 2'); }` is not changing the object contained in the x variable, but is modifing the content of x variable.