# Calling a function from within a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I wanna call a function from inside a dictionary. Is it possible? And if so how would i go about doing it?

```
def function():
    pass

my_dic = {
    'hello': function()
}
```

Comment: Please try to execute the code and let us know if you have any specific questions.

Comment: This is already answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From what I understand, what you actually mean is how to keep the *function reference* inside a dictionary to be able to call it later after getting it from the dictionary by key. This is possible since functions are [*first class objects*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705173/what-is-meant-by-first-class-object) in Python:

```
>>> def function():
...     print("Hello World")
... 
>>> d = {
...     'hello': function  # NOTE: we are not calling the function here - just keeping the reference
... }
>>> d['hello']()
Hello World
```

Relevant thread with some use case samples:

- [Why store a function inside a python dictionary?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/182093/why-store-a-function-inside-a-python-dictionary)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. Just like other types, functions can be stored in a dictionary. The problem in your code is, you are storing the return value of the function *(which is `None` in this case)*, not the function itself.

Remove the parenthesis `()` and you should be good to go:

```
>>> my_dic = {
...    'hello': function
... }

>>> my_dic['hello']()
None
```