# callback function - NodeJS

Tags: node.js

i create an short example and i have a dubt:

```
var request = require("request");
var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=turin&APPID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
module.exports = function (callback) {

    request(
    {
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            callback("Unable to fetch weather"); // callback function
        } else {
            callback("It is " + body.main.temp + " in " + body.name);
        }
    });

    console.log("After request");
};
```

And from external file, i required this module:

```
var weather = require("./weather.js");

weather(function (currentWeather) {
    console.log(currentWeather);
});
```

In this case, i call a `weather` module and i get a `callback` function ( it is an argument of weather module ) for print into command line the weather in Turin. But how it's work?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. The export of `weather.js` is a function. You call that function with a callback function parameter.

Comment: "But how is possible? " I think his real question is "how it's work?"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i call a weather module and i get a callback function ( it is an
>   argument of weather module ) for print into command line the weather
>   in Turin. But how is possible?

Functions in Javascript are a [first class object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705173/what-is-meant-by-first-class-object)
means that you can store a function into a variable and pass it into another function. This pattern is very common on Node.js and in Javasript in general, this is called the [Continuation passing style](https://www.quora.com/What-is-continuation-passing-style-in-functional-programming) ( CPS )

Hope it helps.

Comment: Clear! Thank you so much :)