# How to make an object constructor that takes functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass this simple test for an assignment and I'm having trouble figuring out how to right the constructor function for it,

```
describe("Student", function(){
  var student;

  beforeEach(function(){
    student = new Student({firstName: "Lysette", scores: [100, 100, 100, 4, 100]});
  });

  describe("name", function() {
    it("has a first name", function() {
      expect(student.firstName).toEqual("Lysette");
    });
  });
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
var Student = function (firstName, scores){
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.scores = scores;
};
```

Any Solutions?

Comment: what do yo mean by "doesn't seem to be working"?

Comment: You are passing an object containing two properties, `firstName` and `scores`, and not two separate parameters.  Which of those behaviors do you want?

Comment: What does this have to do with the constructor taking functions?

Answer (score 0):

You may use parameter destructuring (ES6):

```
var Student = function ({firstName, scores}){
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.scores = scores;
};
```

Using this,you can just assign firstName and Scores.

Or old, but bulletproof, and assigning all propertys:

```
var Student = function (changes){
Object.assign( this,changes);
};
```

So you can do:

```
new Student({test:true,name:"test"});
```

Or if you want your original code, you may call it differently:

```
new Student("Jeff",[0,1,1]);
```

As youre expecting *two* parameters in your function...

Comment: @CarlosG90 actually i think the secons one is the best for you. Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destrukturierende_Zuweisung before using the first one...

Answer (score 0):

Since functions are first class objects in JavaScript ([What is meant by 'first class object'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705173/what-is-meant-by-first-class-object)), they can be passed like objects. This would be similar to how you might use a callback.

```
function Student(name, functionToBeCalledWhenCreated) // Constructor{
    this.name = name;
    functionToBeCalledWhenCreated(name);
}
function sayStudentsName(name){
    console.log("This student's name is " + name);
}

var glen = new Student("Glen", console.log); //don't include parenthesis on the function or it will call the function
var owen = new Student("Owen", sayStudentsName);
```

Comment: you need to use `new` keyword: var glen = new Student("Glen", console.log)

Comment: Thanks for the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct student like this:

```
function Student(fields){
   this.firstName = fields.firstName;
   .......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this :

```
class Student
{
  constructor(firstName, scores) 
  {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.scores = scores;
  }
}
var student = new Student('Lysette', [100, 100, 100, 4, 100]);
alert('Name : '+student.firstName+ ' | Scores : '+ student.scores);
```

Comment: This is just syntactic sugar for what the OP is doing already.