# JavaScript, wait for value to change loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to wait for an API to load, however my test code below doesn't seem to be taking the timeout delay into account as it's looping too quickly.

```
var google = false;
  function test(check = false) {
    if (!check) {
      console.log('append the api');

      check = true;
    }
    if (check) {
      console.log('check api is loaded');
      if(!google){
        console.log('not loaded');
        setTimeout(test(true), 10000);
        return;
      } else {
        console.log('loaded');
      }
    }
  }
```

This code should just keep displaying the 2 console.log's until the google variable is changed to true.

I'm unable to change this though as the browser freezes up due to so many loops.

Comment: setTimeout(test(true),1000) => setTimeout(test,1000,true);

Comment: Make an [mcve]. Reduce the complexity, and try again.

Comment: @Jonasw put as answer please?

Comment: Why not use a promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **Jonas w** said you should use `setTimeout(test,1000,true)` instead of `setTimeout(test(true),1000)`, see the explanation below:

According to [MDN WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) you should pass three variables to `setTimeout`:  `function`, `timeout value` and `parameters` which will be passed to invoked function. Functions in JavaScript are [first class objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705173/what-is-meant-by-first-class-object), so you pass them as regular object. In your example you don't actually pass a function but invoke it immediately and to `setTimeout` passed value which returned from this function.

Answer (score 2):

You fault is in this line:

```
setTimeout(test(true), 10000);
```

You must pass the function and dont call it. If you want to pass parameters, do it like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){test(true)}, 10000);
```

Answer (score -1):

You are recursively invoking the `test` function immediately, because you are actually setting the timeout for the value returned by `test`, which is undefined.

You want to put `test(true)` in an anonymous function, like so:

```
var google = false;
function test(check = false) {
  if (!check) {
    console.log('append the api');
    check = true;
  }
  if (check) {
    console.log('check api is loaded');
    if(!google){
      console.log('not loaded');
      setTimeout(() => test(true), 10000);
      return;
    } else {
      console.log('loaded');
    }
  }
}
```

Note the arrow `() =>` – this creates an anonymous function that is invoked when the timeout has elapsed. If you don't like using this newfangled arrow function stuff, you can also write:

```
var google = false;
function test(check = false) {
  if (!check) {
    console.log('append the api');
    check = true;
  }
  if (check) {
    console.log('check api is loaded');
    if(!google){
      console.log('not loaded');
      setTimeout(function () {
        test(true);
      }, 10000);
      return;
    } else {
      console.log('loaded');
    }
  }
}
```