# Sort() pass by parameter? In javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I'm learning javascript and a I got some questions about the sort method in javascript, yes, before you ask I've read the other questions, I understand this:

"Less than 0: "a" is sorted to be a lower index than "b".
Zero: "a" and "b" are considered equal, and no sorting is performed.
Greater than 0: "b" is sorted to be a lower index than "a"."

Thats from the main question about the sort() function, but what I don't understand is:

```js
var array=[5, 2, 1, 10]

 array.sort(function(a,b) {
  return a - b})
```

What is the purpose of the `a` and `b` as parameters in the function, what are value for the parameters that are going to be used during the function? It is told to return `a-b` but who are going to be `a` and `b` during the process? I'm not asking for the `console.log()` example. If `a` and `b` are my paremeter how is the function going to work if I am not even passing the value of `a` and `b`?

In other languages it would be neccesary to pass the values of `a` and `b`.

Comment: Your fundamental problem here seems to be that you don't understand that what you're passing as argument to `sort` is a function. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705173/what-is-meant-by-first-class-object

Comment: Aaa...aren't the answers to all those questions in the documentation ?? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: check this link for full description :- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort   

 and check this part specially:- http://prntscr.com/fxjawn

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Array.sort implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234683/javascript-array-sort-implementation)

Comment: Just for your education, `a` and `b` *are* being passed. They get 'passed' by the `sort` function

Comment: I had read the documentation Sir, a thing that I don't like is that you all act like If the person asking was lazy and didn't care about researching... But, hey I don't care, I'm learning so any help will do. The problem was I didn't know that the sort fuction had another function as parameter, and that function called compareFunction expected the a and b parameters. Anyways, thank you so much for the help, and... you should be a little more polite to those that are new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> compareFunction: Specifies a function that defines the sort
>   order. If omitted, the array is sorted according to each character's
>   Unicode code point value, according to the string conversion of each
>   element.

What you are passing in the array.sort is a function known as the comparator function. What it will do is basically when it will sort your array if will sort it will compare two elements of the array at any given time and sort it according to the implementation details of the provided function.

Lets say you have an array `[2 , 4, 3]`
Given your sort function will pass elements in the comparators to comparators `2,3` and you return the result `2 - 4` which is -2 and you already know < 0 means the the a elements needs to be on lower that is 2 will come first. it will compare `4 - 3` which is > 0 than means a needs to come after.

The Documentation has all the answers to your questions.

[Sort Documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Thanks you Raunak Sett. So that means it doen't matter the name you give to the parameter of ther sort function, it wil still act like the compareFunction?

Comment: Yes its a reference for the sort function, it will call it giving the first parameter as the first element it wants to compare and the second parameter as the other element to compare against.