# calling a function on a function is it possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

in the following code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

express is a function so how it call "express.static('public')" method on it? is it possible in JavaScript to call a function which is inside a function

Comment: good old days of learning Javascript

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A functions is not only a [first class function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function), but also a [first class object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705173/what-is-meant-by-first-class-object) and can contain properties.

```js
function foo() {}

foo.bar = function () { console.log('i am bar'); };

foo.bar();
```

Comment: Yes. From a static, OO point of view, this could be explained as “function application is just a special method you can call on a _function object_, with syntactic sugar that makes it look like maths function application”, i.e. `express()` would be syntactic sugar for `express.<operator"()">()`. From a dynamic, FP view, it would be explained as “OO methods are just special functions that take the name of the method as the first argument”, i.e. `express.static('public')` would be syntactic sugar for `express(<methodname "static">, 'public')`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Neither of those matches the formalism of how it's actually defined in Javascript, though.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The first one actually does. The "`<operator"()">`" method is named [[call]] in the spec, although it is an internal method not a normal object property.

Comment: @Bergi: That's what I mean: [[call]] is special and not just sugar. And it's equally present in named method calls: `foo.bar()` would then be sugar for `foo["bar"].<operator()>()` plus some additional semantics to set `this` appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

You can attach a function as member data to another function (which is what is done in your example).

```
const express = () => {};
express.static = argument => console.log('argument');
express.static('public'); # console >>> 'public'
```

However, you cannot readily access a variable that is defined in a function body.

```
const express = () => {
    const static = argument => console.log('argument');
};
express.static('public'); # console >>> Error: undefined in not a function
```

There is a signifiant difference between member data attached to a function (the first example) and the closure that wraps the body of the function (the second example).

So, to answer your question "is it possible in JavaScript to call a function which is inside a function?" No, this is not readily possible with the important note that this is *not* what is being done in your example.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, it is possible to call a function inside another function in javaScript.
So it depends on the condition, Callback is widely used in js

> (**A callback is a function that is to be executed after another
>   function has finished executing**)

```
function doHomework(subject, callback) {
  alert(`Starting my ${subject} homework.`);
  callback();
}
function alertFinished(){
  alert('Finished my homework');
}
doHomework('math', alertFinished);
```

And the second example can be **Closures**

> **(A closure is a feature in JavaScript where an inner function has 
>   access to the outer (enclosing) function's variables)**

```
function outer() {
   var b = 10;
   function inner() {

         var a = 20; 
         console.log(a+b);
    }
   return inner;
}
```

Comment: While the facts given here are technically correct (and are important ones to know in JS), I don't think this answer the specific question.

Comment: @Pac0 I believe this answer fully satisfies **(is it possible in JavaScript to call a function which is inside a function)**  this part of the question. So there is no reason to vote as a not useful answer!

Comment: @NurridanKudratov I didn't downvote or vote anything, but I strongly believe that when OP is talking about being "inside a function", he was tallkking about functions that could be used as an object while having a member function at the same time (`express` can be executed `()` and also has `static` as member). This case is not among your examples.