# Calling a function without reassigning named argument

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, parameter-passing

I have a function that has named arguments.

I am trying to call the same function from different events without overwriting the values of the others previously assigned.

I have tried store the values of the previously clicked buttons in variables but that doesn't work.

**Is there a way to call the functions and assign a single argument at a time without overwriting the others?**

```js
function mainFun({
  val1,
  val2,
  val3
}) {
  var value1 = val1,
    value2 = val2,
    value3 = val3;
  // console.log(value1, value2, value3);
  console.log(val1, val2, val3);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="mainFun({val1 : 'Caller 1'})">First Event</button>
<button onclick="mainFun({val2 : 'Caller 2'})">Second Event</button>
<button onclick="mainFun({val3 : 'Caller 3'})">Third Event</button>
```

**Trying to achieve:**

> On First Event  > Caller 1 undefined undefined
>
> On Second Event  > Caller 1 Caller 2 undefined
>
> On Third Event   > Caller 1 Caller 2 Caller 3

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your function implementation would have to be significantly different; you'd have to persist those values somewhere. Parameters are effectively local variables to a function, so they're newly created on each function call.

Comment: Is there a similar question on how to `persist` these values? @Pointy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could store the values as property of the function.

```js
function mainFun({ val1 = mainFun.val1, val2 = mainFun.val2, val3 = mainFun.val3 }) {
    mainFun.val1 = val1;
    mainFun.val2 = val2;
    mainFun.val3 = val3;

    console.log(val1, val2, val3);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="mainFun({ val1: 'Caller 1' })">First Event</button>
<button onclick="mainFun({ val2: 'Caller 2' })">Second Event</button>
<button onclick="mainFun({ val3: 'Caller 3' })">Third Event</button>
```

If you do not like to store the values as properties of the function, you could use a closure and return a function for the same group of use cases.

```js
function mainFun(defaults = {}) {
    return function({ val1 = defaults.val1, val2 = defaults.val2, val3 = defaults.val3 }) {
        defaults.val1 = val1;
        defaults.val2 = val2;
        defaults.val3 = val3;

        console.log(val1, val2, val3);
    };
}

var work = mainFun();
```

```html
<button onclick="work({ val1: 'Caller 1' })">First Event</button>
<button onclick="work({ val2: 'Caller 2' })">Second Event</button>
<button onclick="work({ val3: 'Caller 3' })">Third Event</button>
```

Comment: Not my question, just out of curiosity: how/why does this work? Doesn't every onclick create a new instance of mainFunc? (edit: this question referred to your answer before the edit)

Comment: @Frank, no it's always the same function. the values are stored in the properties of the function, because [functions are first class objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705173/what-is-meant-by-first-class-object).

Comment: Exactly what I needed, was trying to avoid using variables inside or outside the scope of the function.

Answer (score 1):

`value1`, `value2`and `value3` variables are local to your `mainFun` function. They're being garbage collected after each `mainFun` execution is done.

To achieve what you want to achieve, you'll need to store the previous parameters somewhere.

There are many possibilities :

- One of them is global variables :

```js
let value1, value2, value3;

function mainFun({
  val1,
  val2,
  val3
}) {
    value1 = val1 || value1;
    value2 = val2 || value2;
    value3 = val3 || value3;
   console.log(value1, value2, value3);
  //console.log(val1, val2, val3);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="mainFun({val1 : 'Caller 1'})">First Event</button>
<button onclick="mainFun({val2 : 'Caller 2'})">Second Event</button>
<button onclick="mainFun({val3 : 'Caller 3'})">Third Event</button>
```

- Another solution would be to store them as the functions properties (as Nina Scholz suggested)

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding your question. But if you want to store te values, you'll have to declare them outside of your function. Currently your values are only alive within your function. When the function is called they will be re-created and after the function finishes they will be deleted again.

You could try to declare your values outside of your function and prevent overriding like this:

```
var value1, value2, value3;
function mainFun({
  val1,
  val2,
  val3
}) {
   value1 = value1 || val1,
    value2 = value2 || val2,
    value3 = value3 || val3;
  console.log(value1, value2, value3);
}
```

what the `value1 || val1` basically does is say 'hey, if `value1` already has a value, use that one. If not, use `val1`.
Acts the same as `value1 = value1 !== undefined ? val1 : value1` or easier:

```
if (value1 === undefined) {
   value1 = val1;
} else { // obviously not needed
   value1 = value1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And valid point but was trying to avoid the `var` altogether.