# Higher Order Functions and Passing Functions as Arguments

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I'm new in JavaScript and just trying to figure out abut this code of line.

As far as I know, the word *operator* is just a random word that could have been anything. But how does it know that the users is referencing to the word add/subtract/multiply/divide when those word also could have been anything else, and lets say its a bunch of other function in that .js file. How does operator return the right inputs?

```js
function add(num1, num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
}
​
function subtract(num1, num2) {
    return num1 - num2;
}
​
function multiply(num1, num2) {
    return num1 * num2;
}
​
function divide(num1, num2) {
    return num1 / num2;
}
​
function calculator(num1, num2, operator) {
    return operator(num1, num2);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean if you do `calculator(1, 2, add)`, how does `operator(num1, num2)` "know" that `operator` is `add`? The function is an object. It doesn't need to be referred to by name. The passed function could be anonymous with no name.

Comment: You are going to need to be more clear. This code doesn't return anything because non of the functions are being called ...

Comment: Currently, this code does nothing. You need to call the functions with the right arguments and use their return values to see any effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `calculator` to actually do anything.

See if this snippet helps:

```js
function add(num1, num2) {
  return num1 + num2;
}
 
function subtract(num1, num2) {
  return num1 - num2;
}
 
function multiply(num1, num2) {
  return num1 * num2;
}
 
function divide(num1, num2) {
  return num1 / num2;
}
 
function calculator(num1, num2, operator) {
  return operator(num1, num2);
}

var a = calculator(3, 2, add);
var b = calculator(3, 3, multiply);
alert('a=' + a + ', b=' + b);
```

The key is to understand that in JavaScript, functions (like `add`) are first-class objects, which can be used as parameters just like integers (`2` or `3`), strings, etc. You can read more here: [What is meant by 'first class object'?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51946807/421195).

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as just using the variable under any name:

```js
function foo(bar) {
    return bar + 1;
}

const something = foo(123); // 124
```

You use the `bar` name inside function, even though the external context doesn't know anything about that name.

In JavaScript you can pass function as any other values, which is makes it possible, for example, to use functions inside other functions:

```js
function zoo() {
    return 3;
}

function foo(bar) {
    return bar() + 1;
}

const something = foo(zoo); // 4
```

Inside `foo()`, we call the `something()` function, even though `foo()` doesn't know anything about that function. It's all about the context and passing values.

Answer (score 0):

`operator` could be any function, not just one of the ones listed there. It could even have side effects. It all depends how `calculator` is called.

For example:

```js
// exactly the same `calculator` function
function calculator(num1, num2, operator) {
    return operator(num1, num2)
}

// new `write` function
function write(num, fontSize) {
    document.write(`<span style="font-size: ${fontSize}px">${num}</span>`)
}

// execution happens here
calculator(99, 200, write)
```