# Are there any other uses of parenthesis in powershell?

Tags: syntax, powershell, language-construct

As new to Powershell world, sometime I'm stuck in the tricky syntax. That's why I'm trying to figure out all the possible uses of the parenthesis inside the language.

**Do you know some more? Can you add here?**

Here mine (left out basic use of curly in pipeline and round in method calls):

```
# empty array
$myarray = @()

# empty hash
$myhash = @{}

# empty script block
$myscript = {}

# variables with special characters
${very strange variable @ stack !! overflow ??}="just an example"

# Single statement expressions
(ls -filter $home\bin\*.ps1).length

# Multi-statement expressions inside strings
"Processes: $($p = “a*”; get-process $p )"

# Multi statement array expression
@( ls c:\; ls d:\)
```

Comment: Only parentheses (`()`) or (following your examples) braces (`{}`) too? What about brackets (`[]`)?

Comment: Yes, braces and brackets also...sorry for my poor english. Anyway braces are not curly brackets (or parenthesis as well)? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cause a statement to yield a result in an expression:

```
($x=3) + 5   # yields 8
```

Comment: Wow. Don't think I'll never use it, it's  tricky anyway! Not able to catch the first statement really. Shouldn't be `($x=3) + 5`?

Comment: Indeed, sorry. There was a `$` missing. That's what you get for writing C# momentarily :-)

Comment: That is odd behavior, but it explains some weirdness I was seeing today.  BTW, your second usage is just variables with special characters.

Comment: @jasonmarcher - actually, his second usage is not really about variables at all. It's an indirection equivalent to get-content, but this is exactly how it works for the variable drive also. $foo is equivalent to ${variable:foo}. Think of "variable:" as the default provider in powershell.

Answer (score 4):

When using generics, you need to wrap the type in `[..]`:

```
New-Object Collections.Generic.LinkedList[string]
```

For some people this might look confusing, because it is similar to indexing in arrays.

Comment: Well, but types are always given in `[]`, e.g. for casts/conversions.

Answer (score 2):

The Param( ) statement (in a function, script, or scriptblock)

Around the condition in an If (or Elseif statement)

Around the expression in a switch statement.

Edit:  Forgot the condition in the while statement.

Edit2:  Also, $() for subexpressions (e.g. in strings).

Comment: About Param, if, switch and while, you are true but they were left out appositely (the same is for **foreach** and **for**). The last you proposed is already in my list. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: Subexpressions are not in the list.

Comment: Might be I'm missing something...are you not referring to this: `"Processes: $($p = “a*”; get-process $p )`, this a subexpression indeed and is in my list.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are arguably a first-class construct in Powershell.

If we're compiling a complete list, we can include the role that square and round brackets play in regular expressions.

An example:

```
$obj.connectionString = $obj.connectionString -replace '(Data Source)=[^;]+', '$1=serverB\SQL2008_R2'
```

Because of the support for XML, you can go so far as to include the square brackets used in XPath. (That's really drawing a long bow though :-)

```
select-xml $config -xpath "./configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name='LocalSqlServer']"
```

Comment: Since regular expressions are always given in strings they are not part of the PowerShell syntax, though. That also makes them definitely not first-class constructs :-)

Comment: Yes, I think so. Regular expressions do not fit here. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I wasn't sure, so making the contentious statement was a good way to test the definition. :-) There's more on the definition of "first-class" here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646794/what-is-a-first-class-programming-construct

Answer (score 1):

The parenthesis is most powerfully.

Suppose that you want collect all output, including errors, of some scriptblock and redirect to a variable or another functions for handle this... With the parenthesis, this is easy task:

```
$customScript = {  "This i as test"; This will be procedure error!  }

(. $customScript 2>&1 ) | %{"CAPTURING SCRIPT OUTPUT: "+$_}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's even written, but not enough clearly in the first short list after "Multi-statement expressions inside strings I'will add

```
# Var property inside a string
$a = get-process a*
write-host "Number of process : $a.length" # Get a list of process and then ".length
Number of process : System.Diagnostics.Process (accelerometerST) System.Diagnostics.Process (AEADISRV) System.Diagnostics.Process (agr64svc).length

write-host "Number of process : $($a.length)" # To get correct number of process
Number of process : 3
```